# How can I change the delay that the MouseHover and MouseLeave events take to fire?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to immediately change the background image of a PictureBox control when the user hovers his mouse over it.

I've implemented the change via the MouseHover and MouseLeave events.

However, it takes several seconds for the event to fire, which makes my application look slow and sluggish.

How can I change the time it takes for the event to fire?

Comment: then use mouse over not "mouse hover"

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I did search for duplicates, but I didn't find any because the title was not descriptive enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to trigger the event immediately, Try use `MouseEnter` event instead

Or `SystemInformation.MouseHoverTime` define the delay for the MouseHover event.

Answer (score 1):

Use MouseHoverTime property
**MouseHoverTime** - Gets the time, in milliseconds, that the mouse pointer has to stay in the hover rectangle before a mouse hover message is generated.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a read-only property.

Comment: my bad, then MouseEnter is way to go